# Reformat file format to be imported to a rational database

Tags: regex

I have a file with the bellow format

```
    1021 set([1, 3, 4, 7, 34, 11, 44])
    1016 set([34, 37, 1, 63, 36])
    1016 set([34, 36])
    1016 set([34, 37, 1, 14, 28, 63, 36])
```

And I need to end up with a table with only the numbers in the brackets.(So I can Import the table to a MySQL database)
So that my final output looks like this:

```
1, 3, 4, 7, 34, 11, 44
34, 37, 1, 63, 36 , NULL , NULL
34, 36 , NULL,  NULL, NULL ,NULL ,NULL
34, 37, 1, 14, 28, 63, 36
```

How do I go by doing this?

Comment: Which regex flavor/language you are using?

Comment: I was thinking if possible to use gitbash on windows or notepad++.But for the latter I am not sure if it will be possible because of the file size.

Comment: This regex on group 1 will give you only the number without the NULL part `\d{4} set\(\[(((\d*, )+)\d+)\]\)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in tree steps with notepad++

1. chop of the first part by replacing `\d{4} set\(\[` with nothing
2. chop of the trailing `])` by replacing `])` with nothing. Remember to change the "Search Mode" to normal or write `\]\)`
3. add the "NULL"s by replacing

`^(\d+)$` with `$1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL`

`^([^,]+(?:,[^,]+){1})$` with `$1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL`

...

`^([^,]+(?:,[^,]+){4})$` with `$1, NULL, NULL, NULL`

`^([^,]+(?:,[^,]+){5})$` with `$1, NULL`